# ListView appears cropped in smaller phones

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I'm having problems with the layout of my listView, in big phones it works great but in the smallest the tittle seems to be cropped from the left and in some cases overlaps with the imageview.

Here's my task_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.usuario.tasker.activities.TasksActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_tasks"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@color/white_title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/titles" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_add_task"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="@color/white_title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/titles" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_tasks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

My item_list_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Título de la tarea"
        android:textColor="@color/white_title"
        android:textSize="@dimen/sub_title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/item_edit"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.481"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_delete"
        android:layout_width="37dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/iconSize"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/item_done"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:tint="@color/white_title"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_edit"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/iconSize"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/iconSize"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/item_delete"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:tint="@color/white_title"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit_black_24dp" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/item_done"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/iconSize"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/iconSize"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:theme="@style/WhiteCheck"

         />


    <View
        android:id="@+id/view4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="#000"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Hay que hacer un backup del servidor"
        android:textColor="@color/white_title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/view4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="31/10/2017"
        android:textColor="@color/white_title"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.843"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/item_description"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_description" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What can I do so that it works in every phone? I think it's probably the fault of the item_list_layout but I'm not sure how to make it better.

Comment: You need to use weight for each and every layout you use. The weight is assigned equally in every devices.

Comment: For Horizontal cropping you need to assign rules to each of your view inside list item . It can be done by assigning Weight or by Relativity using relativeLayout as parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.usuario.tasker.activities.TasksActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_tasks"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:textColor="@color/white_title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/titles" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_add_task"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:text="+"
            android:textColor="@color/white_title"
            android:textSize="@dimen/titles" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_tasks"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>`
```